# link_to causing "Stack level to deep"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to make a link_to for accepting friend requests using the update method in the friends_requests controller. When I click the link it acts like a recursive method with no base case and I end up with a "stack level to deep" error. In the logs I get a bunch of app/models/friendship.rb:11:in `create_inverse_relationship'

edit# For what it's worth I'm using devise for authentication.

The view: users/index

```
<ul>
  New friend requests
  <% @incoming.each do |user| %>
  <% @users.each do |f| %>
  <% if f.id == user.user_id %>
  <li>
    <%= f.name %>
###### id:1 or  id: user.id both lead to the same error.
    <%= link_to "Accept request", friend_request_path(id: 1), :method => :put %>
  </li>
  <% end %>
  <% end %>
</ul>
<% end %>
```

friend_requests controller:

```
class FriendRequestsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_friend_request, except: [:index, :create]

    def index
        @incoming = FriendRequest.where(friend: current_user)
        @outgoing = current_user.friend_requests
    end

    def create
        friend = User.find(params[:friend_id])
        @friend_request = current_user.friend_requests.new(friend: friend)

        if @friend_request.save
            flash[:notice]="Friend request sent."
            redirect_to root_path
        else
            flash[:alert]="Friend request not sent."
            redirect_to root_path
        end
    end

    def update
        @friend_request.accept
        head :no_content
        flash[:notice]="Friend added!"
        redirect_to root_path
    end

    def destroy
        @friend_request.destroy
        head :no_content
    end


    private

    def set_friend_request
        @friend_request = FriendRequest.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

users controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @users = User.all
    @incoming = FriendRequest.where(friend: current_user)
  end

  def show 
    @user = current_user
  end 

end
```

friend_request model:

```
class FriendRequest < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :friend, class_name: 'User'

    # This method will build the actual association and destroy the request
    def accept
        user.friends << friend
        destroy
    end

end
```

friendship model:

```
class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :create_inverse_relationship
  after_destroy :destroy_inverse_relationship

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend, class_name: 'User'

  private

  def create_inverse_relationship
    friend.friendships.create(friend: user)
  end

  def destroy_inverse_relationship
    friendship = friend.friendships.find_by(friend: user)
    friendship.destroy if friendship
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you trace it from the log? Any callbacks in your User model?

Comment: I edited the question. Logs lead me to the create_inverse_relationship method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Friendship, you're calling `#create` in an `after_create` callback, which would invoke the callback again. Depending on your setup, you could probably prevent this by making sure that you only call it when the friendship does not already exist:

```
  def create_inverse_relationship
    if friend.friendships.where(friend: user).blank?
      friend.friendships.create(friend: user)
    end
  end
```

Comment: You can shorten it to one line `friend.friendships.where(friend: user).first_or_create(friend: user)`

Comment: This works, thank you. This type of association is much more complex than I thought it would be.